# Bash script to schedule multiple jobs

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I wonder if it is possible to write a bash script that would do the following:

> make firstprogram

which compiles and executes the first program. Than it would wait until this program is done and then execute:

> make secondprogram

How can I write the bash script so that it is run in the terminal?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. If you just want to run the first command then the second command, simply put them on separate lines in your script. If you want to run the second only if the first succeeds, you could do: make firstprogram && make secondprogram. Does this help?

Comment: What is the problem or question? Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you intend? It will finish the first command before running the next. If you only want to run the second if the first runs successfully (exits with exit code 0), use && instead of ;

```
#!/bin/bash
make firstprogram; make secondprogram
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilize the wait command

```
#!/bin/bash

make firstprogram
firstprogram &
wait
echo "First program done!"
make secondprogram
secondprogram &
echo "Second program done!"
exit 0
```